# Transforming position wavefunction into momentum space wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, wavefunction

I have found the normalisation constant to be C = $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \Delta x}}$. But am struggling with part b, the $\mid x \mid $ in the exponent is what is confusing me. Normally you would change the limits of integration and double the integral but does that apply for indefinite integrals.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The momentum-space wavefunction $\varphi(p)$ is obtained as the Fourier Transform of the position-space wavefunction $\psi(x)$ using:

$$\varphi(p) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\text{d}x\, \psi(x) e^{ipx/\hbar}.$$

(I may be missing a normalisation constant, either $2\pi$ or $\sqrt{2\pi}$, in the definition of the Fourier Transform, I never quite remember, you need to check this.)

Notice how this is *not* an indefinite integral, but a definite one, since one integrates over the variable $x$. Indeed, if this weren't the case, your "momentum-space" wavefunction would be a function of $x$, too! Anyway, you should be able to split the integral into: $$\varphi(p) = \int_{-\infty}^0 \text{d}x\,\psi(x) e^{i p x/\hbar} + \int_{0}^{+\infty} \text{d}x\,\psi(x) e^{i p x/\hbar},$$ both of which are easy enough to evaluate.

This is treading dangerously close to answering a homework-style problem completely, and so this is where I'll stop.

Comment: Thank you! My bad, I did not know about the rules of not asking homework questions.  Although I'm doing this in my free time, not for school.

Comment: @AbeJacob Homework-*style* questions are not limited to questions that are necessarily assigned as "homework", you can read up more about it [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/157014). It's a matter of some disagreement on the site as to what constitutes what, but a general rule of thumb to avoid questions being closed is to have them address a conceptual problem (for example, "How do I compute the momentum wavefunction when the position wavefunction is discontinuous?") rather than a specific computation that won't help anyone who isn't solving that specific question! :)